# Сумма цифр числа в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

У меня есть число `a = 1557`

Как я могу узнать сумму этого числа, если мы берем каждую цифру отдельно (1 + 5 + 5 + 7)

Comment: Как хорошо, что существует гугл, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106989/digital-sum-python

Comment: `sum(map(int, list(str(n))))` :)

Comment: @splash58 `list` не нужен ;)

Comment: @nomnoms12 вечно я в map list засовываю для строк :( Надо будет хоть одну программку написать на pythone, а то обработка спектров у меня пока шелом ограничивается :)

Comment: А вообще этот ресурс не предназначен для решения учебных заданий. Если хотите что-то спросить - надо предоставить свое решение и указать, что именно не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

остаток от целочисленного деления на 10 это последняя цифра числа, просто в цикле складываем эти цифры, отбрасывая использованную цифру целочисленным делением на 10

```
def sum_of_digits(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        sum += num % 10
        num //= 10
    return sum

print(sum_of_digits(1557)) # 18
```

Comment: Думаю, что правильный ответ именно этот, ибо скорее всего это учебное задание, которое требует такого решения.

Answer (score 4):

В питоне это решается так

```
sum(map(int,str(12345)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить так:

```python
print(sum([int(i) for i in list(str(int(input('a='))))]))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `list` тут не нужен, он лишний. А ваше списочное сокращение аналогично `map(int, str(...`, т.е. ваш ответ сводится к ответу `eri` в итоге, только ваш код длиннее и не только за счёт `input()` :)